# SQLite LEFT JOIN Usage is Not Working Correctly

Tags: sqlite, join

I have 3 TABLES. Costumer, Product and Stats. When user select a user and a product, i increase Stats->count by 1.
Stats table has id, cid, pid and count values.
My purpose is sort products by count and they should be alphabetic. This is my sql request;

```
SELECT * FROM product AS p
         LEFT JOIN stat AS s
         ON p._id = s.stats_product_id
         WHERE s.stats_customer_id = 'customerId'
         ORDER BY s.stats_count desc , p.product_name COLLATE NOCASE;
```

The problem is; because i create Stats values after i create some order, at the beginning i can't see all of products. Because some of products that i've never used are not in my Stats table. I know that LEFT JOIN should give me all of products values but it doesn't... Please help me. Thanks in advice.

Ex: I have a,b,c,d,e,f products. Let's think that a,b bought 3 times (their counts are 3), e,f bought 2 times (their counts are 2) and c,d never bought (they are not in stats table because they never bought by anyone and that's the problem tho!). Output order should be:
a
b
e
f
c
d
HANDLED: Solution on answer #1.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the answer. Query should be like this;

```
"SELECT * FROM " +
                        "(product LEFT JOIN stat " +
                        "ON product._id = stat.stats_product_id " +
                        "AND stat.stats_customer_id = '" + customerId + "' ) " +
                        " ORDER BY " +
                        "stat.stats_count desc , product.product_name COLLATE UNICODE";
```

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: You don't need to remove the aliases.